# count number of row in table asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to count number of row of table by created from database. For example in table from database has 3 names A, B,C. It counts A:1 B:1 C:1 in table but it should be 3.

```
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Student Name</th>

        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Records)
        {
             var count = 0;
            <tr>
                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student.Name)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student.SurName)


                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: You set `count` to `0` and then immediately increment it, so yes, it will be `1` when you use it. You need to initialise it to `0` *before* the loop, not inside the loop.

Comment: @nnnnnn So, how can I find the correct answer

Comment: @nnnnnn It dowsnot change 1 1 1 not 1 2 3

Comment: Regarding your edited code, you've still got `count = 0` *inside* the loop, so it will get set back to 0 on every iteration.

Comment: @ nnnnnn Output still is : 1 1 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this

```
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Student Name</th>

    </tr>
    @{
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var item in Model.Records)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student.Name)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student.SurName)

                @if (item.Room.Capacity == 4)
                {
                    count++;
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => count)
                }
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
}
</table>
```

Comment: Yes thank you it is correct 3 3 3 but how can I see 1 2 3 like that?

Comment: It gives an error @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => count++) for count++

Comment: Right, do count++; on the line before the DisplayFor like you had originally and start the count with 0. I also updated the answer

Comment: Thank you so much when count is incremented inside of loop, it fixed.

Comment: var totalCount = Model.Records.Count(item => item.Room.Capacity == 4);